# Word Riddle - you love me or you hate me

Tags: riddle

> With two I’m affirmative
>   With three I’m respectful
>   With four I’m more respectful
>   With all five I’m either loved or hated
>   But when I’m loved, I kill; and when I’m hated, I may save lives.

Comment: Is this a new form of riddle? Or have you seen this before?

Comment: I made this up myself, but I wouldn’t be surprised if this form has already been made.

Comment: Wow, well done, very nice form! I might steal this template to make future riddles xD

Answer (score 65, accepted):

My guess is

> **siren**

With two I'm affirmative

> 'si', which is Spanish for "yes".

With three I'm respectful

> 'sir', a respectful greeting.

With four I'm more respectful

> 'sire', a respectful title.

With all five I’m either loved or hated

But when I’m loved, I kill; and when I’m hated, I may save lives.

> Sirens that were 'loved' led sailors to their deaths. Although they are an annoying noise, their sound means that help is on the way and lives may be saved.

Comment: You got it! I was thinking that the sound of a siren means you’re getting pulled over, but it’s for public safety. But your explanation works too. :)

Comment: Actually, two requires an accent.

Comment: @jpmc26 Anyway, two means "yes" also in French, without accent.