# Is this a Riley? No, it is a Tylo!

Tags: riddle, language

With three I'm a worker
With four I'm against you
With seven I have an anagram that steals
With all eight I save you

*Inspired on [@tyobrien template](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me)*

Comment: MOAR tylo riddles! :D

Comment: Is the L in “Tylo” a play from “Riley”? Just curious. I must say I’m amused. :) Nice puzzle!

Comment: Well, that was just a typo, but I guess that fits well :)

Comment: Change the ‘L’ to a ‘P’ and you’ll get what it is... :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> ANTIBODY.

With three I'm a worker

> ANT(Ants being social workers is a common crossword clue.)

With four I'm against you

> ANTI(Anti-means opposing someone/something)

With seven I have an anagram that steals

> As pointed out by others, this is BANDITO which is Spanish/Mexican for bandit.

With all eight I save you

> ANTIBODY is what saves us from diseases and by extension from death.

Comment: Yeah, the seven bit tripped me up too. Nicely done, +1.

Comment: bandito is Spanish for bandit.

Comment: Wow, that was quick, the anagram can be *bandito*, which means mexican bandit :)

Comment: @GustavoGabriel - in such a case, it might be prudent to add the `language` tag to indicate it also steps outside the realm of English (see the description associated with the tag).

Comment: @Phylyp I must be honest, being an anagram of *bandito* was kind of unintentional, at first I didn't see the missing *o* and thought it was an anagram of *bandit*. But thank you for adding the tag :)