# With three I'm your family, with four I'm in the best family,

Tags: riddle, word

> With three I'm your family
>   With four I'm in the best family
>   With all seven I'm ruled by a family

*Inspired by [@tyobrien's template](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are a

> Kingdom

Because:

> Kin, are your family 
>  King - The best family 
>  Kingdom - ruled by a monarchy

Comment: I knew it was too easy ;)