# A rhyming Tyobrien?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> With three you don't get tired
>   With four if you play with me, you can get fired
>   With six I have an arachnid anagram
>   With all my seven you need to get into a health program

*Inspired by [@tyobrien's template](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me)*

Comment: give us a hint .

Comment: @DeadManWalking Hints are generally provided after 24 hours if nobody solved it...

Comment: is it of the *exact* same format? where every line is a prefix?

Comment: @NL628 Yes. The same format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a guess, some are a stretch...

> Cardiac

With three you don't get tired

> Car -  If you have a car, you can drive everywhere and not walk.

With four if you play with me, you can get fired

> Card - If you play with the company expense card and put too many charges on it, you could get fired

With six I have an arachnid anagram

> Cardia -> Acarid - 6 letter anagram of a subclass of arachnid

With all my seven you need to get into a health program

> Cardiac - If you have heart problems, you'll need a health program

Comment: You got it! Just the arachnid anagram that is incorrect. +1

Comment: Ohhh, I see.  I found another possible solution for the anagram that I think fits better.

Comment: Yep, thats it. :)