# I guess we call these riddles tyos?

Tags: riddle, word

With two I'm a hated person.
With three I'm precious in games.
When all my six is happening you throw it right away.

Inspired by [@tyobrien's template](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me)

Comment: Did you perhaps want to link to [the original riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me) as well?

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Sorry

Comment: You know itll be cool to see something from *your* head. Maybe **you** can start a fad!

Comment: I do what I can just to kill some time.  If you don't like my riddles you don't have to read them! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it

> Ex: for ex girlfriend/boyfriend

and

> Exp: kind of like XP for experience points

and

> Expire: "when all my six is happening" a.k.a when it is expiring, you throw it away...

Comment: Expired is 7 letters long, not 6

Comment: There we go :D lol

Comment: I hope this isn't it. Why hate your ex and exp is not a complete word. But I do still like the answer.

Comment: @John too bad it's apparently correct...lol

Comment: Sorry to disapoint you guys... @John depending on the break up, many people hate their exes. Not that it's always the case.

Comment: Yep that's what I thought :P ...although I'm a sophomore in hs so I wouldn't know...

Comment: @NL628 WTG! Nice!

Comment: @JakeOPJ You're right about exes, that part's ok. But the OG OP used all complete words. Just pointing it out, not disrespecting.

Comment: @John Sure, no offense taken. I'm new here and like to learn more about rules. I appreciate your comment. I just thought that in many games it is written EXP so it was ok. I even thought of XP and windows XP as a hint but it didn't bind. But what is OG OP?

Comment: original poster

Comment: @JakeOPG believe me, my questions haven't always adhered to the "rules". Just trying to help you see another perspective. Referencing another riddle should, in theory, follow those rules unless you imply a divergence. Again I'm not an expert, just sharing my observation. I get the same flak.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answers:

With two I'm a hated person.

> HR for human resources or EX for ex girlfriend

With three I'm precious in games.

> Gem for precious gems in games or EXE for executable files

When all my six is happening you throw it right away.

> This I don't know

Comment: Where does first word in the "three" fits?

Comment: @PaulKaram It is just a guess, if the "three" part was correct, I would try to fit in the "two" part.

Comment: Oh I see now :) good luck :)