# Going tyo to tyo

Tags: riddle

With 3, I'm just a relaxing place to go

With 4, I'm what will happen when you go toe to toe

With 5, try starting a fire and I'll fly you see

With all 7, I'm a light shining ever so brightly

*Inspired by [@tyobrien's template](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me)*

Comment: This is going to be the start of another Riley fad. *Brace yourselves*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you must be

> SPA 
>  SPAR
>  SPARK
>  **SPARKLE**

Comment: that was fast, well done