# A Very Hard Anti-Tyos Riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> With two I am up and close
>
> With three I am nine or eleven
>
> With seven I help people in need
>
> With all eight I am an honest person

**What am I?**

*Here is an example of a Tyos Riddle: [Link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/64120/43256)*
(No offense, Tyos, for the title :P)

**At $50\cdot 2^\text{number of hints}$ views I will add a hint:**

Hint #1:

> I think this riddle is so hard you probably will never find the answer that satisfies *all* of the above requirements.

Hint #2:

> This riddle's answer is an 8-character word whose first 2 characters correlate with the first line, first 3 characters correlate with the second line, and so on. Just like a Tyos Riddle.

Hint #3:

> The first two letters is more of a prefix to a word than an actual word.

Comment: ... Sure, alright, but the last thing I need to see is more "non-Tyos Tyos Riddles"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is the answer a

> Deceiver?

With two I am up and close

> `De` means "down; away" according to google.

With three I am nine or eleven

> `Dec` means "10"

With seven I help people in need

> `Deceive` is when you hurt someone by tricking them

With all eight I am an honest person

> `Deceivers` are not honest people.

And this solution makes sense because

> **Each line is a deceiving one.**

If this is right, this riddle is pretty amazing :D

Comment: Correct! Congratulations!

Comment: There's a tag missing ...? (hehe)

Comment: @Rubio (ROT13) Buuu Qvq lbh zrna gur "yvnef" evqqyr? Jnvg V pna'g qb gung!!!

Comment: @NL628 That's the one - and that's why I was kidding :)

Answer (score 6):

This is **VERY VERY VERY** much of a longshot

Are you

> lines or number of lines

With two I am up and close

> symbol **^** , made by **2** lines

With three I am nine or eleven

> **|X** , made by **3** lines

With seven I help people in need

> **FAQ** , made by **7** lines

With all eight I am an honest person

> Cant figure out this yet

Comment: Sorry but the circle in "Q" is not a line...

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer given by @smriti, I think the answer is:

> Straight
>
>  It matches all the answers given by @smirti plus

With all eight I am an honest person

> Straight is a synonym of honest.