# Do you love me or do you hate me?

Tags: riddle

> If you are scorned and wrathful
>
> I will die for you
>
> If you are full of bliss
>
> I will die for you
>
> If you are wracked with grief
>
> I will die for you
>
> I am loved. I am cherished. I am adored. And so, I am murdered.

Hint:

> I am rarely murdered by myself. Typically, my family and my friends are murdered as well.

Comment: why is the title so similar to https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/64120/43256?

Comment: beautiful poem btw :D

Comment: the title is a coincidence

Comment: I can’t really tell how much poetic license you are using with this hint.

Comment: Of course, I halove you :P

Comment: @kedarguru Probably less poetic license than you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> **flowers**.

```
If you are scorned and wrathful  
I will die for you
```

> People often give flowers to a significant other who is angry at them, as an apology.

```
If you are full of bliss  
I will die for you
```

> Flowers are part of many special occasions, weddings in particular.  ("Wedded bliss")...

```
If you are wrecked with grief  
I will die for you
```

> Flowers are also a traditional part of funerals.

```
I am loved. I am cherished. I am adored. And so, I am murdered.
```

> People love flowers, and to give flowers they must be cut from their plant — that effectively kills them.

Hint:

> `I am rarely murdered by myself. Typically, my family and my friends are murdered as well.`
>  Flowers are rarely given individually; they're usually part of a bouquet or floral arrangement.

Title:

> "She loves me ... she loves me not ...."

Comment: +1 for getting the title :)

Answer (score 4):

Are you...

> Jesus?

Because

> (some believe) Jesus died for all people, no matter if they're wrathful, full of bliss, or grieving.

In addition:

> The last line reminds me of the line "Laudamus te, benedicimus te, adoramus te, glorificamus te" ("We praise Thee, we bless Thee, we adore Thee, we glorify Thee") from the text of the Mass.

And

> Jesus was murdered on the cross.

Comment: The correct answer fits better

Answer (score 2):

> The [tried and tested](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1529063) entertainer, [Bubble wrap](https://www.bbc.co.uk/newsbeat/article/35103515/jumping-on-bubble-wrap-is-one-way-of-staying-happy-this-christmas) comes to mind, and even ice-cream, or a box of tissues. 
>  But I am not sure if any of them fit perfectly.

Comment: Best guesses I've seen so far. But I am more adored than bubble wrap (and I die more for those wrecked with grief than bubble wrap). As for ice cream...I die more for those who are wrathful. Indeed, I perhaps die most prominently for the scorned.

Answer (score 1):

Are you...

> self-composure?

Reasoning:

> a metaphorical death or murder of one's self-composure would certainly result from the more intense-than-usual emotions you've written.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't right, but it kind of fits.

It could be

> life.

If you are scorned and wrathful

> You will do something bad and bad things might happen to you.

If you are full of bliss

> Assuming that bliss = bad narcotics, drugs can make you die.

If you are wrecked with grief

> Then you might die from depression.

I am loved. I am cherished.

> Life is very cherished.

I am murdered.

> Life can be taken away.

Comment: (Is there really value in sharing an answer you admit from the outset isn't right?)

Comment: @Rubio There is a chance, though, isn't there? It fits...

Comment: And I won't get flamed for being "stupid," because I already admitted its low probability of being correct.