# A crimson fish tyo

Tags: riddle

I've seen many people recently posting riddles like [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/64120/43256). I think they are very hard to create, but I've tried anyway. Here it is:

> With two, I'm a beginning
>   With four, that's who I am
>   With all seven, I'm not the greatest
>   But take one out and that I will become.

What am I?

---

**Hint #1**

> With three, I can measure this line

**Hint #2**

> With all seven, I am *almost* the greatest

**Hint #3**

> I had the answer with me but I dropped it and now it's lying here in pieces... I-I-I-I...I'm sorry! T_T

Comment: This needs a knowledge tag if it is only accessible to those who know this subject area.

Comment: @AmitNaidu No, I don't think a knowledge tag is needed here.

Comment: Are we calling these tyo riddles? In analogy to riley riddles?

Comment: @tox123 It's not that widespread, but [at least someone](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=Tyo) calls them this way

Comment: I got pretty far by ”ba” (first letters of the alphabet), ”bass”, ”bassist” and ”assist”, but that falls down, because you are not Bass, I am :-)

Comment: I'm thinking crimson fish tyo means rot13(gur pyhrf pbhyq or n erq ureevat)

Comment: @Cgz I was inspired by you're comment to make an answer, but I was wrong.

Comment: Is the title an Rot13(nantenz)? I also like Cgz's comment

Answer (score 14):

You are

> **[Goldeen](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Goldeen_(Pok%C3%A9mon))**.
>  [image: Goldeen]

> A crimson fish tyo

> You are a red fish, which is also your Pokédex color.

> With two, I'm a beginning

> *Go!* means begin.

> With four, that's who I am

> You are a *gold*$\!$fish Pokémon.

> With all seven, I'm not the greatest

> You are unevolved and certainly not the greatest Pokémon, even in your own family.

> But take one out and that I will become.

> *Golden* can refer to the greatest days or opportunities.

Comment: I like your interpretation, +1 from me! This is not the correct solution though, in particular your interpretation of the second line doesn't fit that well...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I'm going to get this right but I think you are:

> A riddle maker

This is why:

> The tyo riddle itself is just a "crimson fish" or red herring thus the title "A crimson fish tyo".

Further evidence given by:

> The question "What am I" is outside the block quote
>  Early in the question you do use first person with "I've seen many people recently posting riddles like this one. I think they are very hard to create, but I've tried anyway." It is to my belief that these refer to the same "I" which is truly *you* the creator of this riddle

This was inspired by @Cgz's comment

Comment: Nope, sorry. Though you might be on the right direction with the title ;)