# one riddle that is hidden

Tags: knowledge, steganography

> prime number of blue additions
>   STOP IMMEDIATELY!
>   DANGER AHEAD!
>   I look a bit danish
>   just give me a tug

OK, no joke and this is not a hint: I don't know how to solve my own riddle anymore, I took some time off SE, and I forgot about this and now please help, I want to know what it was.

Hint 1:

> Raise each line up to communicate

Hint 2:

> It makes more sense out at c

Hint 3:

> c in Hint 3 is a pun, come on people. Think aboat it.

Comment: Seems like spam XD +1

Comment: @tox123 - does this refer to a thing whose name we have to guess? i.e. is it a _'What am I?'_ riddle?

Comment: @Phylyp on the surface no, but hidden within yes.

Comment: @Bilkokuya nope, I was wrong, can't type.

Answer (score 3):

VERY Partial

> If you click edit you see there are three hidden links:
>  [Word Riddle - you love me or you hate me](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me)
>  [My prefix is food, my suffix is rude](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude)
>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/_____.png
>  Both of the puzzling links are to riddles where you get hints about substrings within a larger word.  Throwing out a guess, we might need to use the clues in this puzzle to find the letters from the answers of the other riddles that make up the `i.stack.imgur` link.

Comment: This is such a vague suggestion, just adding it as a comment here. Potentially the first line "blue additions" may be refering to the 3 "blue" (rude) answers in the second riddle.

Comment: @Bilkokuya no, I didn't even know that was a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> boat

prime number of blue additions

> Blue water.

STOP IMMEDIATELY!
DANGER AHEAD!

> ?

I look a bit danish

> ?

just give me a tug

> Tug boat.

Raise each line up to communicate

> fishing line?

It makes more sense out at c

> lost at "sea"

c in Hint 3 is a pun, come on people. Think aboat it.

> A"boat" it.

Comment: Shame very close, you got part of it but what is c? It means sea but what is it litterally?