# With three I am drunk, with four I have less weight than my brothers,

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> With three I am drunk
>   With four I have less weight than my brothers
>   With five I can measure
>   With six I have an anagram related to goods
>   With all my seven I don't like metaphors

*Inspired by [@tyobrien's template](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me)*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are...

> literal!
>
>  lit = drunk
>  lite = less weight
>  liter = a measure
>  retail = related to goods (anagram of "litera")

Comment: Too fast! :) ${}$

Comment: Welp, that was fast :)

Comment: With 6 I think you're (ROT13) ergnvy!

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: Technically, I could have been faster if there was no minimum character limit on answers. ;)