# TYO: Opposites Attack

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> With two respond to drivel
>
> But three is nearly evil
>
> With five display your pride
>
> While six you wish to hide

Inspired by [@tyobrien's template](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming only six, the word is

> **badger**.

> With two respond to drivel

> **Ba** is a common syllable said by babies, e.g., in "*ba-ba*." Alternatively, "Ba!" is a very dismissive remark.

> But three is nearly evil

> **Bad** is evil to a lesser degree.

> With five display your pride

> A **badge** is a mark of honor and worn with pride.

> While six you wish to hide

> To **badger** or pester someone could cause them to want to escape by hiding.