# Sometimes I have to be very nosy

Tags: riddle

With three I am a prefix for general opinion
With four I have an anagram that you use in boxing
With six I am an action of my whole eight
With my whole eight, sometimes I have to be very nosy

*Inspired by [@tyobrien's template](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With three I am a prefix for general opinion

> Rep - as short for reputation.

With four I have an anagram that you use in boxing

> Repo - with anagram rope, between which boxers are contained and they may fall back on.

With six I am an action of my whole eight, With my whole eight, sometimes I have to be very nosy

> Report and **reporter**, who is nosy doing their job.

Comment: Yes, you got it :)