# With three, you call for me,

Tags: riddle, word

Here is a new Tyo-puzzle inspired by the first [TyoBrien](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me) Puzzle.

> With three, you call for me,
>   With five, you stay in me,
>   With all seven you put belongings in me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are a:

> Cabinet

For the 3 letter clue:

> You hail a cab (Call for me).

For the 5 letter clue:

> You can stay in a cabin.

For the 7 letter clue:

> You store things in the Cabinet.

Comment: That is correct. Good job :D