# With two, I exist

Tags: riddle, word

Another [Tyobrien-style](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me) riddle:

> With three, I cross a river.
>   With four, I am a man.
>   With all five, I am a woman.

**Hint:**

> I didn't say which order I'm adding the letters in.

Comment: We have **Alconja** Puzzles; **Riley** Riddles; and (excluding some more I am probably unaware of) now we have **Tyobrien** Riddles, too? :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With two, I exist

> Am

With three, I cross a river.

> Dam

With four, I am a man.

> Adam

With all five, I am a woman.

> Madam

Comment: No.  All words must be slices of the same 5-letter word.

Comment: @dan04 I only got the last two wrong or all of them?

Comment: None of your answers match the one I had in mind.

Comment: @dan04 I've edited my answer. Do I get it this time?

Comment: Yes, you got it!