# A tyo riddle...why not?

Tags: riddle

> With two I make someone quiet,
>   With three I'm an algorithm,
>   With four I'm fake,
>   With all five I'm dishonor.

Inspired by [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me).

Comment: Ah dammit. I tend to ignore the accepted answers because sometimes there is more than one answer... but it turns out I came to the same result as the accepted answer, anyway. I'll try to find an alternative answer. I have to wait $10$ hours before I can upvote (damn daily voting limit), so I'll favourite :D $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$

Comment: Fun to see these popping up once and a while :)

Comment: Well, I found an alternative, but I don't think it is worthy of an answer. My alternative is $\ast$ (ROT13) ABARG, jurer gur rkcynangvbaf ner boivbhf rkprcg sbe gur ABA cneg (gung pbhyq ersre gb guvf) naq gur ABARG cneg (abarg $\to$ avar $\to$ "arva" juvpu vf Nqbys Uvgyre'f pngpu cuenfr). ABARG, jurer gur rkcynangvbaf ner boivbhf rkprcg sbe gur ABA cneg (gung pbhyq ersre gb guvf) naq gur ABARG cneg (abarg → avar → "arva" juvpu vf Nqbys Uvgyre'f pngpu cuenfr). Nyfb, gur dhrfgvba "jul abg" zvtug freir n uvag, nf gur jbeq ABARG vf fvzvyne gb ABG. $\ast$ I really enjoyed this puzzle, though! :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you are

> Shame

With two I make someone quiet,

> Sh

With three I'm an algorithm,

> [SHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithms)

With four I'm fake,

> Sham

With all five I'm dishonor.

> Shame