# Another tyo riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> With two I'm an airline,
>   With three I'm poor,
>   With five I'm shiny,
>   With all six I'm an animal.

Inspired by [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have deduced it to be

> Badger

With two you are

> BA, British Airways

With three you are

> BAD

With five you are a

> BADGE

With all six you are a

> BADGER