# Don't overthink this: With 1 you have a blind man’s adopted father

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> With 1 you have a blind man’s adopted father
>
> With 2 you can start a fire
>
> With 3 you can make 6
>
> With 4 you can build a doorframe
>
> With 5 and 6, you can pick me up.

Wait… did you think this was going to be a [Tyo Brien puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me)? If so, you're over thinking it.

Comment: Based on the correct answer, I believe it is appropriate you include the `knowledge` tag for this riddle; but other than that, DVL13 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> Stick

Because:
1.

> Adopted father is DareDevil's mentor: Stick

2

> Rub two sticks and start a fire

3

> \ / I = VI = Six

4

> 4 planks of wood will be a doorframe

5

> Nursery rhyme goes "Five-Six pickup sticks"