# 6-letter word that is fit to sell

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

A riddle with a [Tyobrien flavour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/64120/18418)

> With two, I negate
>   With three, I make you unwell
>   With four, I’m the end
>   With all six, I’m fit to sell

Who am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The word is

> Retail

With two, I negate

> '**Il**' can be used to turn things around. Eg: Legal => **Il**legal

With three, I make you unwell

> '**ail**' According to Google, The definition of ail is to feel sick or have pain.

With four, I’m the end

> '**tail**' is a common term for ending. Sometimes used together. Like Tailend batsman in Cricket.

With all six, I’m fit to sell

> **'Retail'** is the term used for a product to be sold.

Comment: Thanks to Nobody and Alconja for helping me complete as I was not thinking away from the normal sequence of the letters.

Answer (score 10):

I think the word could be -

> Detail

Since,

> 'De' is a prefix for negation

and

> 'ail' is an affliction (makes you unwell)

then

> 'tail' is often used to describe the end of objects

And if you have all six

> any object(like a painting or a craft) with a lot of detail is ready to be sold