# With all six, I’m set free

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

A [Tyobrien riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/64120/18418) of the week:

> With three, I’m an animal
>   With four, I’m a cloth
>   With five, I’m a scene
>   With all six, I’m set free

Answer (score 29, accepted):

With three I'm an animal

> ape

With four I'm a cloth

> cape

With five I'm a scene

> scape

With all six I'm set free

> escape

Answer (score 12):

I think you are

> pantou.

With three, I’m an animal

> *Pan* is a genus consisting of chimpanzees and bonobos.

With four, I’m a cloth

> A *pant* is one leg of a pair of pants, which is a garment/cloth.

With five, I’m a scene

> A *panto* is a pantomime, a type of stage production.

With all six, I’m set free

> *Pantou*, spelled in Greek as παντού, means "everywhere".

Comment: That seems quite complicated

Comment: Indeed, but it's all I could think of so far.