# With all five, I work backstage

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Another [Tyobrien riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/64120/18418) of the week:

> With two, I’m active
>   With three I’m first or second
>   With four, I set an example
>   With all five, I work backstage

Hint #1:

> The usage of the word *backstage* may not imply its absolute literal meaning.

Hint #2:

> I may do good if you use me, but bad if I use you.

Hint #3:

> The last letter of the 3-letter word is not part of the 4-letter word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> demon

With two, I’m active

> **on**

With three I’m first or second

> **eon** an era of time.  Could also be **mon** as suggested elsewhere.

With four, I set an example

> **demo** as in demonstration

With all five, I work backstage

> **demon**. in computers, a background process that does work.

Comment: This doesn't bother anyone else here? In computing I've only ever seen it referenced as 'daemon'

Comment: @TCooper I  believe that is an alternate spelling used to try to avoid association with evil supernatural spirits.  (Certain religious people consider the word cannot have any definition but their definition.)

Comment: It is an alternate. Daemon is an older word in general, and particularly relevant in this case, it was less associated with evil than the more modern term demon. Something about spirits in general, some good some bad I believe, some even guide you, etc

Answer (score 8):

I think the answer might be

> Toner

With two, I’m active

> **On** = functioning

With three I’m first or second

> **One** =  which is either the first or second element of the natural numbers, depending on whether you include zero (similar with indexing in computer programming)

With four, I set an example

> **Tone** = general character, quality, or trend (also a frame of mind).

With all five, I work backstage

> **Toner** =  a cosmetic preparation that is applied to produce a required effect, such as one that softens or alters hair colour or one that reduces the oiliness of the skin. Often used by make-up artists in theatrical productions.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought it was (I was pretty certain about it too), but I'm guessing that since a hint's been added since you answered it it can't be what the OP intended?? +1

Comment: @Stiv Indeed, I suspect it might be close though (maybe some of the answers are right). Trying to think what "backstage" could refer to - perhaps a replacement for "upstage" or perhaps it is more metaphorical.

Answer (score 3):

Could you be

> Plego?

As in

> "GO" - to "go" means to be active, as in "all systems go"
>  "EGO" - to have an ego means to put yourself first (or second)
>  "LEGO" - Lego builds commonly model larger structures and can be construed as smaller "examples"
>  "PLEGO" - a web application development company based out of Chicago, apparently, that plays in the front- and back-end development space; this type of company can be construed as "working backstage" of websites or business products

Comment: Not quite, but the final answer is going somewhat about the right direction. So +1 for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

### Third (incorrect) Attempt:

With two

> on (on = active)

With three

> mon (second of week, first work day)

With four

> Amon (Egyptian god)

With five

> Damon (Matt Damon is a producer who works backstage)

---

### Second (incorrect) Attempt:

With two

> on (on = active)

With three

> mon (second of week, first work day)

With four

> monk

With five

> Monks (it's a band name so they most likely work backstage)

---

### First (incorrect) attempt:

With two

> on (on = active)

With three

> con (pro and con / con and pro)

With four

> icon (someone who is an icon sets an example)

With five

> Eicon? (They make communication products that work "backstage" as in no one sees them, but they make everything work)

Comment: Not bad, rot13(bar bs gur nobir vf pbeerpg) have another go.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Is my second attempt closer?

Comment: Closer but not close enough :)

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac How about my third attempt (4th one is definitely more convincing than the others)

Comment: Still not closer, I’m afraid

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Is the second closer than the third?

Comment: I’m giving a +1 since you are closer to the answer than others so far, so don’t stop give up yet!

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac I'm thinking possibly rot13(ZBATB) for the last one. But I'm not sure what the 4 letter word would be

Comment: Not that either

Answer (score 0):

Strongly based on [hexomino's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/94420), I think you are a

> Phone

With two, I’m active

> **on** (in the state of being active, functioning or operating)

With three I’m first or second

> **one** (according to zero-based numbering, the element in position one is the second element rather than one-based numbering, where the element in position one is the first element)

With four, I set an example

> **hone** (a sharpening stone used for removing the burr from the blade of a razor, thus setting an example that all razors should follow if you want to cut more accurately)

With all five, I work backstage

> **phone** (a phone has most ─ if not all ─ of its processing inside, that is, in its "backstage").

Hint #1:

> **The usage of the word *backstage* may not imply its absolute literal meaning.**
>  
>  Backstage is not used literally here, since backstage means *situated in the area behind a stage*.

Hint #2:

> **I may do good if you use me, but bad if I use you.**
>  
>  I think it's something related to the idea of [this article](https://www.commonsensemedia.org/blog/control-your-phone-dont-let-it-control-you).

Comment: Nice attempt, but not close