# With all five, I'm a country

Tags: riddle, word, geography, letters

A [tyobrien](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/64120/18418) riddle inspired by [Ébe Isaac's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94402/with-all-five-i-work-backstage).

> With two, I'm a city
>   With three, I'm a town
>   With four, I'm a village
>   With all five, I'm a country

Edit: There are multiple possible correct answers.

For the one I am thinking of, here are a few hints:

> With two, I was conquered by Israelites

---

> With three, I sound like a dessert

---

> With four, my population is 14 ᵃˢ ᵒᶠ ²⁰⁰⁶

---

> With five, my area is over 500000 km²

Comment: In tyobrien's original riddle, "with two" means specifically the _first_ two letters, etc.; both answers posted so far allow their substrings to lie anywhere within the country name. Would you like to clarify which way you meant it?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Rot13(Gur yrggref ner nqwnprag, ohg abg arprffnevyl ng gur ortvaavat.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the hints, it is now clear that the actual answer is

> Spain

With two, I'm a city

> [Ai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ai_(Canaan))

With three, I'm a town

> [Pai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pai,_Thailand)

With four, I'm a village

> [Pain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain,_Kerman)

With all five, I'm a country

> [Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spain)

**Original Answer**

> Haiti

With two, I'm a city

> [Ai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ai_(Canaan))

With three, I'm a town

> [Ait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ait,_Uttar_Pradesh)

With four, I'm a village

> [Hait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit,_Qasr-e_Qand)

With all five, I'm a country

> [Haiti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiti)

Comment: A valid solution, but not the one I had in mind.

Comment: (Your city is the same as mine but the other three are different)

Comment: Your second answer is the one I had in mind. Very good!

Answer (score 12):

Are you:

> Palau?

With two, I'm a city

> L.A. (Los Angeles, California)

With three, I'm a town

> Lau, Town in Nigeria (and others)

With four, I'm a village

> Pala, Village in Estonia (and others)

With all five, I'm a country

> Palau

Comment: A valid solution, but not the one I had in mind.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you had in mind the country

> Spain

With two, I'm a city

> AI city in Ohio

With three, I'm a town

> Pai town in Thailand

With four, I'm a village

> (Talwandi) Pain village in India

With all five, I'm a country

> Spain

Comment: Correct! This is the answer I had in mind.