# I’m used when nature commands

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

> My prefix deserves a pay
>   My infix is high in demand
>   My postfix permits a stay
>   I’m used when nature commands

Comment: IMO this is too easy. I guessed the answer just from seeing the title in HNQ.

Comment: @Randal'Thor True, I actually wanted to make this one easy :)

Comment: @Randal’Thor you are most welcome to try out my [other question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/94402/18418) as it still stands unanswered ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be

> **TOILET**

Because

> My prefix deserves a pay  - **TOIL** - pay someone for toiling in the field, or other hard work 
>  My infix is high in demand  - **OIL**
>  My postfix permits a stay  - **LET** - rooms to let, rentals
>  I’m used when nature commands - **TOILET** 
>  sorry if I'm way off base. It just makes sense.