# With five, I’m none

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, letters

A [Tyobrien riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/64120/18418) of the week

> With two, I flow
>   With three, I’m one
>   With four, I move
>   With five, I’m none

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With two, I flow

> ac - alternating current flows

With three, I’m one

> ace - one spot in cards

With four, I move

> pace - a step or movement

With five, I’m none

> space - empty region