# With five, I’m a platform

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, letters

A [Tyobrien riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/64120/18418) of the week.

> With two, I’m a metal
>   With three, I’m identified
>   With four, I’m an animal
>   With five, I’m a platform

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With two, I’m a metal

> ag  -  silver

With three, I’m identified

> tag  - such as those added to puzzles posted here

With four, I’m an animal

> stag

With five, I’m a platform

> stage