# A rhyming tyobrien riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> With two, I am something you have from birth.
>
> With three, I am a time to celebrate their worth.
>
> With four, I am a popular dressing or spread.
>
> With all five, some people may call me a head.

*Inspired by [tyobrien's riddle format](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me).*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps:

> ma - A word for mother
>  may - May Day is a common celebration
>  mayo - Shortened form for mayonnaise
>  mayor - A person in charge/head of a city

Comment: For line 2, rot13(Zbguref' Qnl vf va Znl va znal cnegf bs gur jbeyq).

Comment: All four words are correct. Like jafe suggested, rot13(Zbguref' Qnl) is the one I had in mind since it refers back to line 1.